# How to promote Harry Potter questions for the DVD/Blu-ray release?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

"Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows - Part 2" DVD/Blu-ray will be released this Friday (November 11) in North America. I think we could take advantage of this occasion by promoting [existing, already popular, well answered questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter?sort=votes&pagesize=50).

[Recent experience](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/887/where-are-all-these-views-coming-from/890#890) showed that [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/) could be a great platform to promote those questions. From that point, it could speed to twitter or others, But we must pay attention on how we do this:

- The **Title** of the link submission is **HYPER IMPORTANT**. Example, It shouldn't be formulated as a question because [Reddit users will answer it in the comment section of Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/movies/comments/lz7cs/how_long_was_bill_murrays_character_supposed_to/)
- We should not post all question at once, we could separate post by one or 2 days
- Everyone here that have a Reddit account should up-vote those post so they get some attention.

So I propose we discuss :

1. Which Question to promote.
2. Which title we would use for those questions.
3. When those question will be promoted and who will post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I say, take a look at the most popular questions, and post them one at a time. See [this link](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter?sort=votes&pagesize=50). Post one of them every day or two, anyone who wants to, for the next 2-3 weeks, and we should be good. A few choice ones, towards the bottom of the list, include

- [Etymology of the name, "Voldemort."](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/3218/98)
- [Rich Wizards, Poor Muggles](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/3425/98)
- [Why are some muggles allowed to know of the magical world?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/4113/98)
- [How did Snape know how to find Harry?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/5614/98)
- [What happened to the Dursleys?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/4716/98)
- [What child did Harry give the Marauders Map to, if any?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/3274/98)